# Is there a way to copy an existing project with Roslyn workspaces?

Tags: roslyn

I want to make a copy of existing project on disk, remove some source files, add some then save it back to disk with a new file name and in a new directory. Is this possible? The API's that aware of to create a new project require filling in all the details from scratch, but I may miss one, or there could some properties in file which are not supported by the API. I am working with the MSBuildWorkspace object in the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can cause new source files to get added to a project file using MSBuildWorkspace, adding new documents to a project and then applying the changed solution back to the workspace.  It will save the new documents as source files in the project's directory and rewrite the project file with the new documents added.  You can also remove documents (and delete the source files from disk) this way too.

Comment: Thanks very much for you answer I know how modify and existing project but what I want to do is create a new project that starts off as copy of an existing project and then save it to a new file location.

Comment: So far, no workspace supports creating projects (and persisting them) in this way, only adding new document files to existing projects.

Comment: Thanks, so it looks like my best option is to make a copy of the .csproj file.